# Fake desktop environment on Debian server?

Tags: linux, debian, remote-desktop, desktop-environments

I want to run a TeamSpeak 3 Client on my server to serve as a local sound bot. TeamSpeak 3 Client needs a GUI. It is based on Qt. Since TeamSpeak can be controlled from command line, it is not really necessary to waste CPU time for a GUI. So I thought of faking a desktop environment.

What's the best solution to fake a minimal desktop environment on a Debian Linux server? If this is not entirely possible, what would you recommend to waste as less performance as possible? Remember, I really don't need the GUI. It just needs to be there to get TeamSpeak 3 Client started.

Comment: Im no Linux expert, but isnt X lightweight?  If its not actively used, there would be minimal CPU time.

Comment: May I ask you how did you manage to get TS3 Client to be sound bot without GUI? I mean how did you control what you want to stream? I am very interested in that.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin, I just set up TeamSpeak once with a real gui, different profiles, added them to the bookmarks and checked "Connect on TS3 Client start". Then I configured pulseaudio server and created a different audio channel in pulse for every bot-user I wanted to have. After that, I just set the different audio channels and audio input in the client. Once it worked, I disabled the real gui and replaced it with the fake desktop environment. Everything works as expected. The bots (channel switching etc.) have been controlled via the server query protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use the [X Virtual Frame Buffer](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml). It will act as a regular X server, but will discard any data that is fed to it. You can install it on Debian with `sudo apt-get install xvfb`.

You can use it like this:

```
/usr/bin/Xvfb :10 &   # This will launch Xvfb
export DISPLAY=:10.0
/path/to/teamspeak3
```

You could of course also integrate this in the Teamspeak init script.

Comment: Also: `Xephyr`, `Xnest`.

Comment: @kostix I think Xephyr and Xnest only work if you already have an X server running. They are able to run an X server within an X server. If there is no X server I don't think they'll work.

Comment: @mtak, indeed you're right. Sorry for the confusion!